# StructureMap Inject GetInstance Method

Tags: c#, structuremap

I'm using *structuremap* in a project and for a specific need I want to have access to the **Container.GetInstance(Type type)** method from structuremap.
Thinking about onion architecture, I don't wan't to have the nuget *structuremap* referenced in every projects of my solution.

So I have a class in a **Core** project that's supposed to do something like that:

```
public class CommandDispatcherBase
{
    public async Task<TCommandResult> DispatchAsync<TCommand, TCommandResult>(TCommand command) 
    {
        // This line
        CommandHandler<TCommand> handler = GetInstance(typeof(CommandHandler<TCommand>)));
        handler.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

With :

```
public abstract class CommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    // Some methods
}
```

And :

```
public class RegisterUserHandler : CommandHandler<RegisterUserCommand>
{
    // Some methods
}
```

And in my bootstrap registry :

```
For<CommandHandler<RegisterUserCommand>>().Use<RegisterUserHandler>();
```

But I have no idea how to do. Ideally I would like to have a **delegate** method in my **Core** project like that :

```
public delegate object CommandHandlerFactory(Type handlerType);
```

In which I would inject the **Container.GetInstance(Type type)** structuremap method but I don't know how to do that.

Any idea ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have a look at the `QueryProcessor` class [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Comment: Works like a charm, it was the pattern I looked for ! THANKS !